# Errors learning Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new with this language, so, I'm practicing with some exercises I found online, this one says that given an "array" you've to return the number

I.e.:

```
func([1,22,4],R).

R= 1224.
```

OK, so... I think I've an idea to make it, but like I said, I'm pretty noob with this so, here it is,

I take the "head" of the array and power it by the length of the "array", then, take the tail and repeat the process...

This is something I found online:

```
power(0,N,0) :- N>0.
power(X,0,1) :- X>0.
power(X,N,V) :- X>0, N>0, N1 is N-1, power(X,N1,V1), V is V1*X.
```

My code:

```
func(Number,Answer) :-
    Pow is length(Number,P),
    trab(Number,Number,R,Pow).

trab(Number,[X|XS],R,Pot) :-
    R1 is (power(X,Pow),R2),
    R is R+R1,
    trab(Numero,XS,R,Pot-1).
```

I know its all wrong but, can you guys help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The example suggests that the `func/2` predicate is simply concatenating all the elements in the list passed in the first argument. If so, take a look at the documentation of the standard predicates `number_codes/2`, `atom_codes/2`, and `atom_concat/3`. Also note that the `func/2` predicate will need to "walk" the list, which can be easily accomplished using a recursive definition. Finally, note that you will need a way to accumulate the intermediate concatenation result until you reach the end of the input list.

Answer (score 1):

cheating (SWI-Prolog only):

```
func(A,B) :- atomic_list_concat(A,T),atom_number(T,B).
```

now to your code:

```
func(Number,Answer):-
  Pow is length(Number,P), % P is a singleton
  trab(Number,Number,R,Pow). % R is a singleton
```

the amended syntax could be

```
func(Numbers,Answer):-
  length(Numbers,Pow),
  trab(Numbers,Pow,Answer).
```

but it will not work anyway: you have elements that can take more than 1 digit position
(like 22), then is illusory to precompute the leftmost, as the Pow was intended to do.
Instead, you must walk down the list till the last element, where the exponent is 0

```
?- X is 10^0.
X = 1.
```

and compute the exponent to 'pass back' for the left digits, accounting for the number magnitute. It's complicated... let's assume we have input numbers of max 2 digits (0..99), then the base case could be

```
trab([Digit], Pow, Answer) :-
  Expo is 0,
  Answer is Digit * 10^Expo,
  increment_expo(Digit, Expo, Pow).
```

and increment_expo must check if Digit falls in 0..9 or 10..99 etc.

note: differently than you code, Pow is an output, not an input.

Far easier would be to follow Paulo suggestion.

Comment: The upvote is for your "cheating" suggestion. This is not at all cheating, `atomic_list_concat/2` is a perfectly fine predicate and if it is not available, it is easy to implement.

Comment: Easy to implement but a Prolog implementation can be expensive due to all the intermediate lists and atoms created that would need to be garbage collected. A "native" implementation can (and should be) more efficient. The good news is that this predicate is becoming a de facto standard predicate thanks to the work in the Prolog Commons group.

Comment: @PauloMoura: Prolog Commons group ? thanks, can't believe I didn't heard before !

Comment: The de facto standard `dialect` and `version_data` Prolog flags were also a product from this group.

Comment: @PauloMoura: I've added a link from Prolog tag page.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use an accumulator which contains the number representing the list before the part that still has to be processed.

You have to multiply the accumulator with 10 to the power of the number of the digits of the first element of the list and add the first element to it. Then you can continue recursively. If the list is empty, we are finished:

```
func(List,N) :-
    func2(List,0,N).

func2([],Acc,Acc).   % Base case: just return the accumulator
func2([H|T],Acc,N) :-
    Digits is floor(log(10,H)) + 1,   % Digits is the numbers of digits
    % integer(...) is needed because ** returns a float:
    NewAcc is Acc * integer(10**Digits) + H,
    func2(T,NewAcc,N).
```

**Update**: I realized that `log/2` is SICStus-specific, for SWI use `log10(H)` instead of `log(10,H)`.